# How can I use a struct type as the dictionary key type when serializing a Dictionary with Protobuf?

Tags: c#, dictionary, serialization, deserialization, protobuf-net

I have the following declaration for a class:

```cs
    [Serializable]
    [ProtoContract]
    public class TheClass : TheBaseClass // Not the real names!
    {
        public TheClass(Guid operationId, Dictionary<MyStruct, int> expectedNumbers)
        {
            // Initializing inherited properties.
            this.OperationId = operationId;
            this.ExpectedNumbers = expectedNumbers;
        }

        [MessagePackMember(10)]
        [ProtoMember(10)]
        public Dictionary<MyStruct, int> ExpectedNumbers { get; set; } =
            new Dictionary<MyStruct, int>();
    }
```

`MyStruct` is a struct type, and it also has decorations for ProtoBuf to (de)serialize it.

It looks like `ExpectedNumbers` is not being (de)serialized correctly, as I've seen some *NullReferenceException*s being thrown while iterating over this dictionary, specifically when retrieving the `Key` of the dictionary.

I have two questions now:

1. Can complex-type Dictionaries be (de)serialized using Protobuf?
2. What is wrong with the decoration for `ExpectedNumbers`?

Thank you!